# How can I force the MySQL client to output to stdout or a log file when importing a SQL file?

Tags: mysql, import, logging

Let's say I am importing a small SQL file using the MySQL client like so:

```
mysql < 10k-file.sql
```

The mysql client does not output anything. How can I force it to show how many rows are affected for each query, errors, so on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  general log

so enable [general log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html)

but be careful this will log everything what happens and gets fast big

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
mysql < 10k-file.sql > import.log 2>&1
```

This will import the dump and send any messages to import.log The `2>&1` sends error messages to the log.

if there was an error, it will stop the import.

In that case, use this

```
mysql --force < 10k-file.sql > import.log 2>&1
```

Comment: You need the verbose option to make it print the statements and number of rows affected: `mysql -v -v --force < 10k-file.sql > import.log 2>&1` Note that the `-v` is given twice to make it **more** verbose.